# Tilde operator in C

Tags: c, int, unsigned, short

```
 unsigned short int i = 0;
 printf("%u\n",~i);
```

Why does this code return a 32 bit number in the console? It should be 16 bit, since short is 2 bytes.

The output is 4,294,967,295 and it should be 65,535.

Comment: "since short is 2 bytes." No, this is implementation defined.

Comment: @PhilipKendall `short` is 2 bytes on all but the weirdest implementations.

Comment: The fundamentals of this answer revolve around the integer promotion rules.

Comment: Isn't `%u` for an `int`, instead of a `short int`? Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8699826/2703418).

Comment: @BennoZeeman: `%u` expects an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to mention `unsigned`. Cheers. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%u` expects an `unsigned int`; if you want to print an `unsigned short int`, use `%hu`.

**EDIT**

Lundin is correct that `~i` will be converted to type `int` before being passed to `printf`.  `i` is also converted to `int` by virtue of being passed to a variadic function.  However, `printf` will convert the argument back to `unsigned short` before printing if the `%hu` conversion specifier is used:

> **7.21.6.1 The fprintf function**
> ...
> 3 The format shall be a multibyte character sequence, beginning and ending in its initial
> shift state. The format is composed of zero or more directives: ordinary multibyte
> characters (not `%`), which are copied unchanged to the output stream; and conversion
> specifications, each of which results in fetching zero or more subsequent arguments,
> **converting them, if applicable, according to the corresponding conversion specifier**, and
> then writing the result to the output stream.
> ...
> 7 The length modifiers and their meanings are:
> ...
> `h` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a
> `short int` or `unsigned short int` argument (**the argument will
> have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall
> be converted to `short int` or `unsigned short int` before printing**);
> or that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `short
> int` argument.

Emphasis mine.

So, the behavior is *not* undefined; it would only be undefined if either `i` or `~i` were not integral types.

Comment: This works. What would be the equivalent for unsigned long int then? and long long int?

Comment: @Greyshack For a `long unsigned int`, use `%lu`; for a `long long unsigned int` use `%llu`.

Comment: `~i` is however never of type `unsigned short int`. I believe `printf("%hu\n",~i);` invokes undefined behavior because you are passing an `int` to a printf which expects `unsigned short`.

Comment: @Greyshack: There's a nice table of the various options here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: @Lundin: Not really. `printf()` is a variadic function so even if you passed just `i` it would be promoted.

Answer (score 4):

When you pass an argument to `printf` and that argument is of integer type shorter than `int`, it is implicitly promoted to `int` as per K&R argument promotion rules. Thus your `printf`-call actually behaves like:

```
printf("%u\n", (int)~i);
```

Notice that this is undefined behavior since you told `printf` that the argument has an `unsigned` type whereas `int` is actually a signed type. Convert `i` to `unsigned short` and then to `unsigned`to resolve the undefined behavior and your problem:

```
printf("%u\n", (unsigned)(unsigned short)~i);
```

Comment: The argument is already of type int when passed to printf, because of integer promotion caused by `~`. `(int)~i` is 100% equivalent to `~i`. Also the cast `(unsigned)(unsigned short)~i` is nonsense, simply do `(unsigned int)~i`.

Comment: @Lundin I have to correct you. `(unsigned)(unsigned short)~i` is not equal to `(unsigned int)~i`. For instance, on a platform with a 16 bit `short` and a 32 bit `int` with `i == 1`, `(unsigned)(unsigned short)~i` has the value `0xfffe` whereas `(unsigned int)~i` has the value `0xfffffffe`.

Comment: @FUZxxl But it is still nonsense, why would you ever want the unsigned short to be implicitly promoted to a signed type, then invert that signed type, and then trucate that result?

Comment: @Lundin Because `int` might have the same size as a `short`. If we used `printf("%d\n", (unsigned short)~i)`, the result would come out incorrectly where `short` and `int` have the same size.

Answer (score 4):

N1570 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators p4:

> The result of the ~ operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand (that is,
>   each bit in the result is set if and only if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is
>   not set). **The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the
>   promoted type.** ...

Integer type smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`. If `sizeof(unsigned short) == 2` and `sizeof(int) == 4`, then resulting type is `int`.

And what's more, `printf` conversion specifier `%u` expects `unsigned int`, so representation of `int` is interpreted as `unsigned int`. You are basically lying to compiler, and this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: The only good answer, which didn't fail to point out that the `~` operator has already promoted the variable to type `int` before it is passed to printf. `printf("%d\n",~i);` would have worked just fine and that is _not_ because of some printf argument promotion!

Comment: This only tells half of the story; yes, arguments to `printf` are promoted, but then `printf` will *convert them to the appropriate type* based on the conversion specifier.  See my edited answer above.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the arguments to `printf()` are put into the stack in words, as there is no way inside printf to know that the argument is short. Also by using `%u` format you are merely stating that you are passing an unsigned number.

Comment: this is undefined behaviour, as the expression `(~i)&0xffff` has type `int` whereas `%u` expects an argument of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: But he is not passing a short, he is passing an int.