# Printf and Scanf not working properly for second string input

Tags: c

I'm trying to simply read input from the user and store a CD record into some variables. All the variables details are correctly printed out for all the variables except for the second array of `char` for `artist` which isn't printing anything. I've tried to deal with the extra character spacing by introducing the space at the front of each of my formatted strings in `scanf()`, but that hasn't fixed it.

```
void displayCDInfo(char* title, char* artist, short noOfTracks, int isAlbum, float price);

int main()
{
    char title[61];
    char artist[41];
    short noOfTracks = 0;
    int isAlbum = 0;
    float price = 0.0;
    char albumOrSingleResponse;

    printf("Please enter the title: ");
    scanf(" %s", title);

    printf("Please enter the artist: ");
    scanf(" %s", artist);

    printf("Please enter the number of records: ");
    scanf(" %d", &noOfTracks);

    printf("Please enter whether or not the cd is an album/single (A or S): ");
    scanf(" %c", &albumOrSingleResponse);

    if(albumOrSingleResponse == 'A')
    {
        isAlbum = 1;
    }

    printf("Please enter the price of the CD: ");
    scanf(" %f", &price);

   displayCDInfo(title, artist, noOfTracks, isAlbum, price);

   return 0;
}

void displayCDInfo(char* title, char* artist, short noOfTracks, int isAlbum, float price)
{
    printf("\nThe title of the CD is %s", title);
    printf("\nThe name of the artist is %s", artist);
    printf("\nThe number of tracks on this CD are %d", noOfTracks);
    printf("\nThe CD is an %s", (isAlbum == 1) ? "album" : "single");
    printf("\nThe price of the cd is $%.2f", price);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps using `%s` is not a good idea - see [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) - One assumes that some titles are multiple words

Comment: Only give space for the second and fourth scanf statement

Comment: %s doesnt work with even one word, and gets and puts are demonstrating the same problem

Comment: A space on the second and fourth statement still doesn't fix it

Comment: As an starting point change `scanf(" %s", title);` to `scanf("%s", title);`

Comment: never use scanf("%s", ..); (why do this so many beginners?). better use fgets(), alternative use scanf("%"MAXLEN"s",...). otherwise you can get a array overflow and UB really fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this now whilst keeping `noOfTracks` as a short. Since I was using `"%d"` for scanf on the Number of tracks variable I was overwriting the space allocated for the previous variable which was artist, hence why it wasn't being displayed. To solve this I had to change the `"%d"` to `"%hu"` for short int.

```
void displayCDInfo(char* title, char* artist, short noOfTracks, int isAlbum, float price);

int main()
{
    char title[61];
    char artist[41];
    short noOfTracks = 0;
    int isAlbum = 0;
    float price = 0.0;
    char albumOrSingleResponse;

    printf("Please enter the title: ");
    scanf("%s", title);

    printf("Please enter the artist: ");
    scanf("%s", artist);

    printf("Please enter the number of records: ");
    scanf("%hu", &noOfTracks);

    printf("Please enter whether or not the cd is an album/single (A or S): ");
    scanf(" %c", &albumOrSingleResponse);

    if(albumOrSingleResponse == 'A')
    {
        isAlbum = 1;
    }

    printf("Please enter the price of the CD: ");
    scanf(" %f", &price);

    displayCDInfo(title, artist, noOfTracks, isAlbum, price);

    return 0;
}

void displayCDInfo(char* title, char* artist, short noOfTracks, int isAlbum, float price)
{
    printf("\nThe title of the CD is %s", title);
    printf("\nThe name of the artist is %s", artist);
    printf("\nThe number of tracks on this CD are %hu", noOfTracks);
    printf("\nThe CD is an %s", (isAlbum == 1) ? "album" : "single");
    printf("\nThe price of the cd is $%.2f", price);
}
```

Comment: It seems that you were getting a warning as you declared `noOfTracks` as `short` but used `"%d"` (`int`) format to print it. As a side note: You can always compile your program with: `gcc -Wall -Wextra your_file.c` , it will give you `all` and `extra` hidden warnings :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space: `scanf("%s", ...)` 
and add a space: `scanf(" %c", ..)`

```
int main()
{
    char title[61];
    char artist[41];
    short noOfTracks = 0;
    int isAlbum = 0;
    float price = 0.0;
    char albumOrSingleResponse;

    printf("Please enter the title: ");

scanf("%s", title);

printf("Please enter the artist: ");
scanf("%s", artist);

printf("Please enter the number of records: ");
scanf("%hu", &noOfTracks);

printf("Please enter whether or not the cd is an album/single (A or S): ");
scanf(" %c", &albumOrSingleResponse);

if(albumOrSingleResponse == 'A')
{
    isAlbum = 1;


   }

    printf("Please enter the price of the CD: ");
    scanf("%f", &price);

   displayCDInfo(title, artist, noOfTracks, isAlbum, price);

   return 0;
}
```

Because when you add a space before `" %c"` it consumes newline characters entered with previous inputs.

Edit: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699812/what-is-the-format-specifier-for-unsigned-short-int), you may use `"%hu"` for printing the `short` to avoid any warning.

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Just move the position of char array declaration from top of main body.

```
void displayCDInfo(char* title, char* artist, short noOfTracks, int isAlbum, float price);

int main()
{
    short noOfTracks = 0;
    int isAlbum = 0;
    float price = 0.0;
    char albumOrSingleResponse;
    char title[61];
    char artist[41];

    printf("Please enter the title: ");
    scanf(" %s", title);

    printf("Please enter the artist: ");
    scanf(" %s", artist);

    printf("Please enter the number of records: ");
    scanf(" %d", &noOfTracks);

    printf("Please enter whether or not the cd is an album/single (A or S): ");
    scanf(" %c", &albumOrSingleResponse);

    if(albumOrSingleResponse == 'A')
    {
        isAlbum = 1;
    }

    printf("Please enter the price of the CD: ");
    scanf(" %f", &price);

   displayCDInfo(title, artist, noOfTracks, isAlbum, price);

   return 0;
}

void displayCDInfo(char* title, char* artist, short noOfTracks, int isAlbum, float price)
{
    printf("\nThe title of the CD is %s", title);
    printf("\nThe name of the artist is %s", artist);
    printf("\nThe number of tracks on this CD are %d", noOfTracks);
    printf("\nThe CD is an %s", (isAlbum == 1) ? "album" : "single");
    printf("\nThe price of the cd is $%.2f", price);
}
```