# How it is possible to turn unsigned int to negative number with bit shift?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Why do i get negative number when executing this?

```
unsigned int a = 1 << 31;
printf("%d",a);
```

I already checked size of integer on my computer and it is 4 Bytes. So my integer number is consisted of 32 bits and doing 31 shifts to the left I should get until the most significant bit. That means that it should be positive number, but i always get negative.

What I get : -2147483648

What I expected : Some positive number ( probably 1073741824)

What am I missing here?

Comment: you're printing it as signed!

Comment: `printf("%u",a);` should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the fact that you're bit shifting. You are simply not printing in the corresponding format.

%d or %i is for printing int, and thus when you try to print your unsigned int, it is converted into an signed int.

See here: [What is the format specifier for unsigned short int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699812/what-is-the-format-specifier-for-unsigned-short-int)

or https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_30.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use %u as the printf format string.

Meaning:

```
printf("%u",a);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the wrong format specifier you're using (`%d` instead of `%u`), you're probably invoking undefined behaviour by shifting a 1 into the sign bit of the `int` operand, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009922/3233393).
To fix it, use an unsigned literal:

```
unsigned int a = 1u << 31;
//                ^
```