# different ports in netstat and program

Tags: c, sockets

I have this simple TCP echo server, and whenever a client connects to it, it displays the client's IP and port.  But when I run `netstat -a`, a different port for the client is shown. I'm running the server and client on the same computer.

In my program, it shows `client connected: 127.0.0.1:34997`, but the result of `netstat -a|grep 6969` is:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6969            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:46472         localhost:6969          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:6969          localhost:46472         ESTABLISHED
```

The code of echo server is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int listenfd,confd,n;
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    pid_t pid;
    char buffer[100];

    memset(&server,0,sizeof server);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port=htons(6969);

    listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    
    if(bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof server)==-1){
        perror("bind error");return-1;
    }

    if(listen(listenfd,20)==-1){
        perror("listen error");return -1;
    }
    printf("listening for connection..\n");

    for(;;){
        socklen_t cllen = sizeof(client);
        confd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&cllen);
        
        
        if((pid=fork())==0){    
            printf("client connected: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),client.sin_port);
            close(listenfd);
            for(;;){
                n=read(confd,&buffer,sizeof buffer);
                if(n==0) break;
                write(confd,&buffer,n);
            }
            printf("client disconnected: %s:%d",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),client.sin_port);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(confd);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so that we can try to reproduce the behavior you're asking about?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the code that accepts the connection and determines and prints the client's port number.

Comment: ok i edited the post

Comment: [htons](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htons). Try printing them both in hex: they're the same two bytes in a different order. sin_port is documented as being in network byte order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to byte flip the `client.sin_port`.

```
printf("client connected: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));
```

34997 is 0x88B5.  Flip the endianess of those bytes to 0xB588, and you have 46472, as shown in your `netstat` output.  More information on the [`ntohs` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs).

Note that `client.sin_addr` is most likely an `unsigned short` (see `struct sockaddr_in` definitions [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) and [here](https://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/sockaddr_inman.html), check your own system), but this [will be promoted to an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702610/3476780), so the `%d` format specifier is fine.